# Abnormally high memory usage Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows, memory, bsod, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with my MS Windows Server 2008 R2 - every one-two days server causes BSOD with error 0x0000001d with tcpip.sys driver. There is abnormal huge amount of nonpaged pool bytes in poolmon.

I tried to troubleshoot this strange behavior - poolmon said me that there is a lot of memory used by netio.sys (tag - Nnnn), and when I tried to trace it using xperf - there was a really unclear details for me - most of memory used by n/a stack of Nnnn. Can you help me with resolving this issue?

[image: poolmon screenshot]

[image: xperf screenshot]

Comment: Nnnn = **NetIO NetBuffers And NetBufferLists**. Load Debug symbols in WPA: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh448108.aspx and expand the netio.sys stack, maybe you see a 3rd party driver in the stack

Comment: I checked it, there is no 3rd party drivers. About an year server was working fine, and without any changes starts to crash unexpectedly

Comment: can you share the ETL so that I can take a look at it?

Comment: sure, [here is a link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75725922/2/pool.etl)

Comment: you had some 3rd party stuff in the stack. check my answer and try it. Maybe it helps.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the trace I can see 3rd party drivers (`E1G6032E.sys` - Intel Ethernet driver and `fweng.sys` - Microsoft Forefront driver) involved:

[image]

Here are some steps that you can try:

- uninstall/Update Forefront
- update VMware (in the ETL I see that you run 2008 R2 in VMware: VMware Virtual Platform) and the guest tools to get a newer `E1G6032E.sys` driver.
- Install the [Convenience rollup update for Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-US/kb/3125574) (because the `netio.sys` is a bit old (`6.1.7601.18327 (win7sp1_gdr.131125-2337)`) because the rollup includes a lot of perf/memory related fixes that may also fix the leak if the 2 other steps haven't fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! It's working for me, I updated VMWare Tools on guest OS and installed KB3125574, so now two days there is no memory leaks in the system.